# Determine nth-of-type upon keyup in input Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wasn't able to find an answer searching, so I figured I would ask.

I have multiple inputs with the same name, i.e.

```
<form>
    <input name="entities[]" class="entities-text" type="text" />
    <input name="entities[]" class="entities-text" type="text" />
    <input name="entities[]" class="entities-text" type="text" />
</form>
```

Using Jquery, how would I determine which "nth" the input is upon keyup?  I started something as:

```
$("form").on('keyup', 'input[name="entities[]"]', function() {
    var input = $(this)'
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://api/jquery.com/index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/):

```js
$(function() {  
  $("form").on('keyup', 'input[name="entities[]"]', function() {
    var input = $(this);
    console.log( input.index() );
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input name="entities[]" class="entities-text" type="text" />
    <input name="entities[]" class="entities-text" type="text" />
    <input name="entities[]" class="entities-text" type="text" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I just found the same answer searching a different way.  I'll accept it once I can.